# Generador de algoritmo de Luhn

Tags: c++

Buenas quisiera pedir ayuda con un proyecto que tengo que hacer es generar un rango numerico de 10 digitos y guardarlo en un archivo, intente hacer algo en c++ pero los vectores no me permiten procesar numeros tan grandes. Que podria implementar?, tendria que hacerlo en otro lenguaje si alguien tiene una sugerencia se lo agradeceria

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int cedu=123266;    
int cedula[cedu], ced[cedu], 
pares[cedu], impares[cedu], total[cedu], 
dec[cedu], dectotal[cedu];
int a[cedu] ,b[cedu] ,c[cedu] ,d[cedu] ,e[cedu] ,f[cedu] ,g[cedu] ,h[cedu] ,i[cedu] ,j[cedu];
int n, m=0;
for (n=0; n<123266; n++){   
cout<<"Ingrese su cedula n: "<<n<<endl;
cedula[n]=n;
ced[n]=cedula[n];
a[n]=cedula[n]/1000000000;
cedula[n]=cedula[n]-(a[n]*1000000000);
b[n]=cedula[n]/100000000;
cedula[n]=cedula[n]-(b[n]*100000000);
c[n]=cedula[n]/10000000;
cedula[n]=cedula[n]-(c[n]*10000000);
d[n]=cedula[n]/1000000;
cedula[n]=cedula[n]-(d[n]*1000000);
e[n]=cedula[n]/100000;
cedula[n]=cedula[n]-(e[n]*100000);
f[n]=cedula[n]/10000;
cedula[n]=cedula[n]-(f[n]*10000);
g[n]=cedula[n]/1000;
cedula[n]=cedula[n]-(g[n]*1000);
h[n]=cedula[n]/100;
cedula[n]=cedula[n]-(h[n]*100);
i[n]=cedula[n]/10;
cedula[n]=cedula[n]-(i[n]*10);
j[n]=cedula[n]/1;
cedula[n]=cedula[n]-(j[n]*1);

//cout<<cedula<<endl<<a<<endl<<b<<endl<<c<<endl<<d<<endl<<e<<endl<<f<<endl<<g<<endl<<h<<endl<<i<<endl<<j<<endl;
if (cedula[n]>2400000000){
    cout<<"Numero de cedula invalido."<<endl;
}
else{       
    pares[n]=b[n]+d[n]+f[n]+h[n];
    a[n]=a[n]*2;
    if (a[n]>9){
        a[n]=a[n]%10+a[n]/10;
        }       
    c[n]=c[n]*2;
    if (c[n]>9){
        c[n]=c[n]%10+c[n]/10;
        }
    e[n]=e[n]*2;
    if (e[n]>9){
        e[n]=e[n]%10+e[n]/10;
        }
    g[n]=g[n]*2;
    if (g[n]>9){
        g[n]=g[n]%10+g[n]/10;
        }
    i[n]=i[n]*2;
    if (i[n]>9){
        i[n]=i[n]%10+i[n]/10;
        }
    impares[n]=a[n]+c[n]+e[n]+g[n]+i[n];
    total[n]=pares[n]+impares[n];   
    } 
    dec[n]=0;   
    while (dec[n]-total[n]!=j[n] && dec[n]<total[n]+10){
        dec[n]=dec[n]+10;
        dectotal[n]=dec[n]-total[n];
    }       
}
ofstream fs("Cedula.txt");
cout<<endl;
for (n=0; n<123266; n++){       
    m++;
    if (dectotal[n]==j[n]){
        ced[m]=ced[n];          
        if(a[n]==0){
        cout<<"0"<<ced[m]<<endl;
        fs<<"0"<<ced[m]<<endl;
        }
        else{
        cout<<ced[m]<<endl;
        fs<<ced[m]<<endl;
        }
    }
    else{
    }       
}
fs.close();     
return 0;
}
```

Hasta aca solo procesa 123266 números

Comment: Por favor, las ediciones de la pregunta no deben servir para ir modificando tu pregunta sobre la marcha. Deberías mantener el código original pues si no las respuestas que se han publicado dejan de ser válidas. Si tienes dudas nuevas tienes que publicar una nueva pregunta

Answer (score 1):

`int` es un tipo de 32 bits con signo, luego el valor máximo que puedes almacenar en una variable de este tipo es `2^31 - 1 = 2.147.483.647`. Si pretendes almacenar números de 10 dígitos en este tipo vamos mal, ya que la inmensa mayoría de esos números *no entran*.

Para solucionar esto tienes a tu disposición el tipo `long long`, que son 64 bits con signo, y `unsigned long long` para trabajar sin signo. El rango de estos tipos se incrementa apreciablemente respecto a los tipos de 32 bits:

```
long long          -> 2^63 - 1 =  9.223.372.036.854.775.807
unsigned long long -> 2^64 - 1 = 18.446.744.073.709.551.615
```

Como ves, estos tipos soportan números de hasta 19/20 dígitos, luego no deberías tener problemas para trabajar con números de 10 dígitos

---

> intente cambiarle el tipo de dato unsigned long long y agrandar el vector a 10 digitos pero al compilar me sale el error violacion de segmento

Un clásico en el mundo C++:

```
int cedu=10;    
int cedula[cedu], ced[cedu],
```

Si `cedula`, `ced`, y compañía tienen 10 elementos, el rango de iteración debe ser de `0` a `9`  y no de `1` a `10`:

```
// BIEN
for (n=0; n<10; n++){  

// MAL
for (n=1; n<=10; n++){
```

Por otro lado, ten en cuenta que `cedu` es **una variable**, por lo que `cedula`, `cedu` y demás pasan a ser *VLA* (Variable Length Array). Este tipo de elementos no es válido según el estándar de C++, luego tu código no será portable y puede dar problemas en algunos compiladores. Te sugiero cambiar la declaración de `cedu`:

```
int const cedu = 10;
```

De esta forma le dejas claro al compilador que `cedu` es una constante y que su valor no va a cambiar, lo que te quita el problema de la portabilidad.

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia intente cambiarle el tipo de dato unsigned long long y agrandar el vector a 10 digitos pero al compilar me sale el error violacion de segmento.

Comment: Al darle el tamaño a la variable cedu unsigned long long cedu = 123266 es lo maximo que me permite, pienso que deberia ser un numero mas grande pueda que mi compilador no procese mas numeros o otra cosa estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: @Arifactory. `cedu` lo usas para darle tamaño a arrays que están **en la pila**. Para arrays grandes tienes que usar memoria dinámica. Tendrás que usar `new` y `delete` para crear los arrays